# How to return a type that mapped to variadic position

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I'm enjoying learning about meta-programming, and started find out about some features, I can't make the call to at works which takes an index to return a type that mapped to varidiac position.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>
#include <utility>

template <typename...>
struct type_list {};

template<typename T ,typename... Ns>
auto pop_front(type_list<T, Ns...> t) {
    return type_list<Ns...>{};
}

template<typename T ,typename... Ns>
auto front(type_list<T, Ns...> t) 
{
    return type_list<T>{};
}

template<typename T ,typename... Ns>
auto at(type_list<T, Ns...> t, size_t i)
{
    if (i) return at(pop_front(t), i-1);
    return front(t);
}

int main()
{
    type_list<int, bool, float> x;
    at(x,2);
}
```

Comment: The return type must be known at compile time. You cannot change that at runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If we move the index into the template paramters so that it becomes a compile time constant then we can leverage [`std::tuple_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_element) to get the type at the supplied index like

```
template<size_t Idx, typename... Ts>
auto at(type_list<Ts...>)
{
    return std::tuple_element_t<Idx, std::tuple<Ts...>>{};
}
```

and then we can call it like

```
at<2>(x);
```

It should be noted that this approach requires all types in the list to be default constructible.

---

If you are only ever going to use `at` in a context like `decltype(at<2>(x))` then you actually don't need to define the function and can instead use what I call a "meta function" like

```
template<size_t Idx, typename... Ts>
auto at(type_list<Ts...>t) -> std::tuple_element_t<Idx, std::tuple<Ts...>>;
```

and now you can't run this function, but you can use it an any unevaluated context, like in `decltype(at<2>(x))`, and the types in the list do not need to be default constructible.

Comment: this didn't work, using your function, 
type_list<int, bool, float> x;
    std::cout << std::is_same_v<decltype(at<2>(x)), float> << '\n';

Comment: @G.Adam I forgot that `tuple_element` itself doesn't resolve into a type but it has a `type` member.  I have updated the answer to correct that.

Comment: now it works, but this involoves type conversion from type_list to std::tuple correct?

Comment: @G.Adam No, no conversion happens.  `std::tuple_element<Idx, std::tuple<Ts...>>` "creates" a type, but types don't take up any space or have a value, they are just a name.

Comment: @G.Adam No problem.  I also updated the answer again to use `std::tuple_element_t`, which does resolve to a type in place of the more verbose `typename std::tuple_element_t<Idx, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type`